# How to use GraphQL enums in frontend code (e.g. in a <select>)?

Tags: graphql, apollo, appsync-apollo-client

I have a simple GraphQL enum defined like the following:

```
enum PassType {
    DailyFit
    StarterFit
    MonthlyFit
    QuarterlyFit
    DoubleFit
    MultiFit10
    MultiFit20
}
```

I would like to reuse these values in a `<select>` tag. I'm using Apollo and AWS Appync as a GraphQL infrastructure. Is there a way to get these from the Apollo client without duplicating them on the frontend manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can utilize an [introspection](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Introspection) query to fetch information about any particular type in your schema, including enums. Utilizing Apollo's `Query` component, this would look something like:

```
const PASS_TYPE_QUERY = gql`
  query GetEnum {
    __type(name: "PassType") {
      enumValues {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`

<Query query={PASS_TYPE_QUERY}>
  {({ data }) => {
    // Handle loading/errors as usual
    if (!data.__type) {
      return null
    }
    return (
      <select>
        {data.__type.enumValues.map(enumValue => (
          <option value={enumValue.name}>{enumValue.name}</option>
        ))}   
      </select>
    )
  }}
</Query>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel I need to configure a project using **react**, **PWA** and **Link-state apollo**
Can please you guide to some tutorial So that I can configure it at the best level.